# pthread_mutex_timedlock not timing out

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

OS: Linux

lib: glibc

I have multiple threads which access a piece of hardware and I am preventing contention by using a mutex.

The software is very complex and its possible deadlocks may be in the system due to recursive calls to take the lock. For this reason I am using 'pthread_mutex_timedlock' instead of 'pthread_mutex_lock'. I would rather print an error message and continue than causing the system to watchdog and reset. This would allow me to see the issue without bringing the system down.

Here a snippets of code that should help you understand what I am trying to do.

```
pthread_mutex_t MainMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

#define m_TAKE_LOCK()   { \
                          struct timespec abs_time; \
                          clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME , &abs_time); \
                          abs_time.tv_sec += 5; \
                          if (pthread_mutex_timedlock (&MainMutex, &abs_time) != 0) \
                          { \
                              printf("Lock failed PID %d %s\n",  getpid(), __func__); \
                          } \
                        }

#define m_RELEASE_LOCK() pthread_mutex_unlock(&MainMutex);

void func1(void) {m_TAKE_LOCK()}
void func2(void) {m_TAKE_LOCK()}

void main(void)
{
  while (1)
  {
    func1();
    func2();
    m_RELEASE_LOCK()
    ...
  }
}
```

There are other threads that also take the lock but that is not an issue. The problem I am having is that the timeout on the lock never occurs. It waits forever and watchdogs the system which is precisely what I am trying to avoid.

The 'abs_time.tv_sec' is correct - I have printed it and the system clock is already initialized by the time I try and use it.

I understand Windows will prevent a lock on the same process but Linux has no such protection. I realize I should not be recursively calling m_TAKE_LOCK() but the purpose of using the timedlock is to catch bugs (print a message and continue).

Any one know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: If you use `pthread_mutexattr_settype(3posix)` to set the mutex to type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE`, you should be able to recursively acquire your locks within a single thread.

Comment: Style issue: you should use `do { ... } while(0)` instead of `{ ... }`, since it will allow to append a `;` to its invocation -- which is much nicer. And use it for both TAKE and RELEASE.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot attempt to acquire a mutex you already hold. It's not permitted. You are assuming that it will produce a specific result and there is no guarantee it will do so.

You should be using a recursive mutex. And you should release it the same number of times you acquire it.

However, fundamentally, it is an absolute requirement that any code that acquires a mutex know, for sure, what mutexes it holds while it is running that relate to code that function might call into directly or indirectly. (It does not need to know about 'higher-level' mutexes held by code that calls it but untouched by functions it could ever call into.)

So, for example, if you are making a class called "Foo" that calls into "Bar", every function of the "Foo" class must know about any locks it holds that are associated with "Foo" or "Bar". If some new class, "Qux" calls it, the "Foo" code need not know what "Qux" locks are held, but if "Qux" calls into "Foo" while holding a lock on "Bar", the "Foo" function *must* know this. You must implement a sane lock hierarchy. (Unless you fully understand the rationale for this rule and know for sure that it doesn't apply.) Otherwise, your code will never work right except occasionally by luck.

The [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html) does not require it to time out: "If the mutex cannot be locked without waiting for another thread to unlock the mutex, this wait shall be terminated when the specified timeout expires." There is no other thread to wait for. Nor does it require an error, "The pthread_mutex_timedlock() function may fail if:
[EDEADLK] A deadlock condition was detected or the current thread already owns the mutex." "May" indicates error conditions whose support is optional, the term "shall fail if" is used to indicate required behavior.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. Your quote of the posix spec makes is clear but I overlooked it. I will investigate a recursive lock. It seems that is better suited to my needs to prevent a system hang during unintended recursive calls to the mutex lock.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works well on my linux machine:

```
nils@doofnase:~$ gcc test.c -o test -lpthread -lrt
nils@doofnase:~$ ./test
Lock failed PID 2333 func2
Lock failed PID 2333 func2
Lock failed PID 2333 func2
Lock failed PID 2333 func2
^C
```

This is the output I would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. Sometimes I get so obsessed working on an embedded system I forget I can check it out on my Linux machine.

Comment: That is the nature of code that breaks the rules -- sometimes it does what you expect and sometimes it doesn't. However, your expectation is, IMO, wrong. POSIX says, ["If the mutex cannot be locked without waiting for another thread to unlock the mutex, this wait shall be terminated when the specified timeout expires."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html). There is no other thread to wait for here. EDEADLCK detection is not required, it's a "may".